# Tomcat SSL: No trusted certificate found

Tags: tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, keytool

I created a certificate using keytool:

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA
```

Exported and imported it into my keystore:

```
keytool -export -alias tomcat name.crt
keytool -import -file name.crt
```

When I do keytool -list I have 2 entries:

```
tomcat, Sept 15, 2010, keyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): ...
mykey, Sept 17, 2010, trustedCertEntry
Certificate fingerprint (MD5):...
```

Note that the fingerprints for both entries are the same.

I configured my server.xml to point to my .keystore file

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="${user.home}/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />

<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="443" />
```

But in my tomcat logs I see when I perform an action in my Java app:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
...
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found
```

Is there any other configuration that needs to be done?

Comment: Do you do anything between `-export` and `-import` (why re-import what you've just exported)? Did you put the full hostname when `keytool` asks "*What is your first and last name?*" (that's for the Common Name in fact)? Is your application trying to connect to the server itself (it would be useful to see more of the stack trace).

Comment: I re-imported it because I thought it had to be a trustedCertEntry. I don't have a hostname ATM. Can I use my IP address instead?

Answer (score 1):

You need the client (i.e. the browser) to trust your servers certificates.

For this you either import the certificate of the server in the browser as a trusted certificate, which only works when you have the browser under your control. Or you get your certificate signed by a trusted authority, which costs money.

exporting and reimporting under a different name doesn't make any sense.

Update:

I think I start to understand what you are trying to do. You want a java client access a webapp via https. yes?

In this case you need to provide a 'truststore' i.e. a keystore containing the trusted certificates. You'll want to set the system Property javax.net.ssl.trustStore to the name of the truststore to use.

You'll probably can use a handcrafted TrustManager as well. This site seems to give information about that:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html

This simple example might help as well: http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

Comment: I did import the certificate to my browser.  So I can't use a self-signed certificate?